# Ubuntu 23.10 Firmware Updater doesn't work correctly

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 I noticed that there's no Firmware Updater, so I installed it manually but application doesn't work  correctly. It starts, white blank window  with spinning logo Ubuntu circle arrives and it stays until I stop it.Reading various threads, I realized that this is a fairly common issue. I installed Gnome Firmware, which starts instantly but I can't upgrade UEFI.dbx because of Update error "Blocked executable in the ESP" it's to common issue.Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

swnw